# C++ memory spaces

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have read through the C++ standard. However, what type of memory space are allocated and how it ties to scope and lifetime is not very clear. I will give my basic understanding but if gurus can either correct/enhance this with side rules/examples will help.

We will keep it simple to *single* threaded applications:

1. Heap - dynamic memory usually using new/malloc
2. Stack - e.g. where auto variables go
3. Static space -- where static variables go ?
4. Some other kinds of spaces used by the implementation *NOT* accessible to the program ?
5. what other memory space is available although the C++ standard refers to an *abstract* machine

SCOPE:
Has to do with visibility of the identifier (i.e. name/reference)

LIFETIME:
Start/end time of memory allocated/de-allocated

Other related question is any algorithms / white papers to re-write malloc etc.

Comment: If you have the standard in front of you, read again sections 3.7 and 3.8, and also 1.8.

Comment: I did read it. But what about question 5 above ?

Comment: The answer to almost all the questions is that "it is up to the implementation". For 4) I can offer "space for exception objects".

Answer (score 0):

- "Heap" / *dynamic* allocation `new`/`delete` `malloc`/`realloc`/`free`

  - lifetime until `delete` / `realloc(p, 0)` / `free`
- stack - used for many function arguments and function-local variables

  - lifetime until smallest enclosing scope exits / whether `for`/`while`/`if` or `{}`-enclosed block, or function
  - (sometimes arguments/vars may be in CPU registers instead, but any side-effects of leaving scope will happen at times "as if" they were on the stack)
- global, namespace-scope variables, class/struct static members, function-static variables / most compilers/OS support a grouping/separation in memory of read-only (i.e. `const`) from read-write variables (so they can enforce read-only memory access using CPU memory management), and often of initialised-to-0 from statically initialised-to-non-0 data (so they can simply map in areas of the executable image containing initial non-0 values)

  - regardless of how they're grouped in memory, function-local statics needing runtime-initialisation perform that initialisation the first time the function's called, while for the non-function variables the scope is defined by guaranteed in-order construction within each translation unit / object file, unspecified order amongst object files, all of which happens before entering `main()`, and destruction in reverse order of that after `main()` exits
  - an exception is runtime-loaded objects (e.g. with `dlopen()` et al), which - predictably - perform any necessary initialisation when loaded, and objects stay in scope until either unloaded or program termination
- thread-local storage: typically implemented by reserving memory at the start of the function's "stack", where the lifetime can match the thread's
- as Kerrek SB comments, space may be set aside for objects being thrown, decoupling their lifetime from the unwinding stack, but details are up to the implementation; this area will be used when throwing "by value", with the lifetime extending to the end of the first catch block that doesn't re-throw the same object